# Using object directly from another class c++

Tags: c++, c++11

Hi i have 3 classes that i want to use. but i dont want to create object of one class more than once. I directly want to use the object (in third class) of one class declared and initialized in second class.

To understand the problem please focus on NetworkConnection members and class defined in example below.

Class Mainwindow header

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include "secondscreen.h"
#include "networkconnection.h"

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();
    NetworkConnection *NetworkConnectionObject;

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    SecondScreen* SecondScreenObject;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

Class Main Window cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include  "QMessageBox"
#include "networkconnection.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    NetworkConnectionObject = new NetworkConnection();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{

    int Error  =  NetworkConnectionObject->Connect(Username,Password);

     ///////////////
     // This Works
     //////////////
    NetworkConnectionObject->LogInToken = "";

}
```

Class NetworkConnection Header

```
#ifndef NETWORKCONNECTION_H
#define NETWORKCONNECTION_H

#include <QString>


class NetworkConnection
{
public:
    NetworkConnection();
    int Connect(QString Username, QString Passwd);
    QString LogInToken;
};

#endif // NETWORKCONNECTION_H
```

Now i want to use Networkclassobject directly in SeconScreenclass so that i can access LogInToken Member of MainWindowInstance.

```
#include "secondscreen.h"
#include "ui_secondscreen.h"
#include "mainwindow.cpp"

SecondScreen::SecondScreen(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::SecondScreen)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

      ///////////////
     // This doesnot work
     //////////////

    MainWindow::NetworkConnectionObject->LogInToken = "";

}

SecondScreen::~SecondScreen()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

However, when i try this compiler says 
`Invalid use of non-static data member "MainWindow::NetworkConnectionObject"` Problem is i dont want to declare it static. Is there any way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing `secondscreen.h` I can't say for sure but `MainWindow::NetworkConnectionObject"` doesn't reference a specific instance of `MainWindow` class, you must reference a specific instance to modify.

---

If in your `SecondScreen` header you have something like

```
class SecondScreen {
  // . . .
  MainWindow window;
  // . . .
}
```

then in your constructor for `SecondScreen` you must use the initialized instance of `MainWindow`, i.e.

```
SecondScreen::SecondScreen(QWidget* parent) : QDialog(parent) {
  window.NetworkConnectionObject->LogInToken = "";
}
```